# Binary tree traversal using linklist

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, binary-tree, tree-traversal

If level order traversal is better than rest traversal then what it the use of learning them in binary search tree?

Level order traversal seems to fetch information easily as compared to inorder and pre order traversal.

Comment: In level order traversal you will need extra space i.e. Queue to process the traversal but in other traversals no need for extra space. The other thing is Binary Search Tree has some specific applications that can be easily predicted by its property(value of the left node is smaller and that of the right node is greater than node). So level order traversal is rarely performed.

Comment: @learner-coder "other traversals" (inorder, pre-order, post-order) do require extra space. Every recursive call requires a new stack frame. In a balanced tree, the recursion depth is only `log n`. If the tree isn't balanced, the recursion depth could be `n`. You don't see the extra space because it's allocated on the stack implicitly, as opposed to the explicit queue you'd need for a level-order traversal, but it's definitely there.

Comment: The different traversals provide data in a different order, which can be quite useful. See the answers to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186667/usefulness-of-pre-and-post-order-traversal-of-binary-trees for examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of problem that can be easily solved by the preorder and postorder recursive implementation. To name a few:
- Finding boundary traversal of a tree
- Making a doubly linked list from a binary tree

and many more.

preorder and postorder traversal also use internal call stack of platform, which is not the part of the memory constraints(in some cases). But using level order require queue that uses extra memory

Comment: Can you give me an example of when the internal call stack space used is not part of the memory constraints?